# Error while file upload via form data using jQuery

Tags: jquery, file, upload

I am facing error while uploading a file via Formdata using jQuery.

> Error details - Required request body is missing. The input message is not readable.

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48ToX.png)

1. Why are the boundary values different?
2. Why is the service failing? Is something wrong with my form data? Please compare it with success screenshot.

[Successful call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZeCY.png)

```js
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('object', JSON.stringify({
  "properties": {
    "object_name": "Test Doc4",
    "r_object_type": "eri_wg_doc",
    "eri_document_type": "Agenda",
    "eri_conf_class": "Ericsson Confidential",
    "eri_audience": "Workgroup Members - Restricted",
    "ignore-number": false,
    "allow-new-version": false
  }
}));

formData.append('content', files[0]);

var aData = jQuery.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "multipart/form-data;boundary=----LGZlKL2faC2ilpCJ",
  headers: {
    "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa("username" + ":" + "password"),
    "accept": "application/json"
  },
  url: "https://domain/repositories/folders/0b004cff89977940/documents?skipSSO=true",
  processData: false,
  data: formData,
  success: function(data, status) {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

Comment: Your "contentType" code does not *change* the boundary that jquery uses.  It tells the backend what the boundary will be without actually changing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the problem is because you set your own `contentType` and boundary. This is not correct practice when uploading files through jQuery AJAX.

The correct practice is to use `contentType: false` when supplying a `FormData` object to the `data` property. jQuery will then configure the `contentType` header itself, and keep the boundaries consistent.